# How to turn off passwords?

Tags: startup, password, firestarter

When I start Firestarter, the firewall program asks for my password. How do I turn off my Firestarter password?  I want Firestarter to start on computer startup but it won't because it's password protected.

Answer (score 0):

Firestarter is a program for *editing* your firewall rules - the firewall is part of the linux kernel and will automatically start whether or not you run Firestarter.

So, you don't need to do anything with passwords to have a firewall - it's already there.  In fact, you should keep your password enabled, since that way no one but you will be able to *edit* the firewall rules.